# Changing route parameters when a different dropdown option is selected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a dropdown in my application, and I want it so that when a user selects a different option from the dropdown, it should update the url.

For example, if I have a `DropDown` component like such:

```
class DropDown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        <DropDownOption name="foo" />
        <DropDownOption name="bar" />
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

And a `DropDownOption` component like such:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';  

class DropDownOption extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
      <option>
        <Link to={`/value=${this.props.name}`}>
        </Link>
      </option>
    );
  }
}
```

If the user clicks on the dropdown then selects 'foo', the url would change to for example: "`localhost:3000/value=foo`",
and when they select 'bar', it would change to "`localhost:3000/value=bar`"

However, this doesn't work because `<option>` tag cannot have an `<a>` tag inside of it, but I was hoping to do it using `<Link>` from the `react-router-dom` module because I have been using it in other places (eg. for buttons) to change the route parameters and it has worked fine.

Any suggestions how I can implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach an `onChange` event to the select and in it push to the `history` object that the router passes as a prop.

Edit:

here's an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/w031p82nr5